# Angular.js and WebApi which returns int array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

For testing with angular I've a Webapi method which returns an instance of an object that conatins a List. (The json output can be seen below)

Now in my angular controller i want to retrieve this object.

Does anyone have a hint what I'm doing wrong?

RestResource as **factory**

```
myngApp.factory("valueResource", function ($resource) {

    var result =
        {
            database: $resource("/api/values")
        }

    return result;
});
```

**Controller**:

```
myngApp.controller("dataController", function ($scope, settings, valueResource) {
    $scope.message = "Hello World!";
    $scope.userName = settings.user;


    $scope.restValues = valueResource.database.query({});
});
```

the **json response** (taken with fiddler) is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpca2lsblxleHBlcmltZW50YWxcc3JjXG5nMlxXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcV2ViQXBpXHZhbHVlcw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Feb 2014 14:47:35 GMT
Content-Length: 19

{"Items":[1,2,3,4]}
```

Console output is:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:55671/api/values". angular.js:8013
Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js:6:450
    at p.then.m.$resolved (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-resource.min.js:8:517)
    at A (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js:93:5)
    at A (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js:93:5)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js:94:173
    at h.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js:102:456)
    at h.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js:100:218)
    at h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js:103:264)
    at f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js:67:120) angular.js:9435
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the error and its documentation

[http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24resource/badcfg)

it is clear that query should return an array, whereas yours is an object with a single property Items.

Use the `get` method on the resource.

Comment: Thx i expected that for testing single objects would work. My fault :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for $resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) indicates that creating models should be done in a different manner. If you just want to make an XHR request to this URL, I'd use the $http service instead and resolve the promise this returns in the view.